# Django - Dynamic ChoiceField - All images in static dir

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to create an app that will allow the user to choose an image between all those contained into a specific folder. The dropdown input would render a thumbnail of the image and the filename. **The choice value would be the path of the image.**

I know it could be possible to do it with [jQuery UI and javascript](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown), but I would like to know how I could generate the choices dynamically in the form in order to get the visual effect needed.

If you have other ideas, thank you for any suggestion

dynamic form (not complete):

```
filename_list = ???
path_list = ???
images_thumbnails_list = ???

class imagesForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(imagesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['selectedImage'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=
                         for path in path_list: str(path),
                         for filename in filename_list: str(filename)
                         for thumbnail in images_thumbnails_list: thumbnail )
```

example of input field needed:

```
  <select name="webmenu" id="webmenu">
    <option value="calendar" data-image="icons/icon_calendar.gif">Calendar</option>
    <option value="shopping_cart" data-image="icons/icon_cart.gif">Shopping Cart</option>
    <option value="cd" data-image="icons/icon_cd.gif">CD</option>
    <option value="email"  selected="selected" title="icons/icon_email.gif">Email</option>
    <option value="faq" data-image="icons/icon_faq.gif">FAQ</option>
    <option value="games" data-image="icons/icon_games.gif">Games</option>
  </select>
```

visual example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good solution for this task would be making a model for you choices

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(length=255)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='static_directory')
```

and use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) to populate those data

```
countries_list = Countries.objects.all()

class imagesForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(imagesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['selectedImage'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=countries_list)
```

and render them in your templates like this

```
{% for country in field.choices %}
    <option value="{{country.id}}"><img src="{{country.image.url}}"/> {{country.name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that's the solution. I see you put the {{ country.id }} as the choice value. Is it possible to put the country object instead? I guess only in the form save() method?

Comment: you can put a serialised object but that would be a _very bad_ decision, I think you should stick with the id, if you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask and if you found my answer helpful please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I have tested your solution, its very close to work, the problem is in the template, {% for country in field.choices %} is not looping, probably the wrong way to access the choices